# php: Routing in CI (Codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-routing

I really have a hard time understanding the URL/URI routing in CI. In this instance, I have two links, one is Home and the other is Panel, Home links to main/index and panel links to main/panel, heres the snippet to better understand.

```
<a href="main/index"> Home </a>
<a href="main/panel"> Panel </a>
```

and this is the code for the controller `main.php`

```
class Main extends CI_Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->view('templates/header');
        $this->load->view('home');
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }

    public function panel()
    {
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->view('templates/header');
        $this->load->view('panel');
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }
}
```

and heres my `routes (config/routes.php)`

```
$route['main/index'] = "main/index";
$route['main/panel'] = "main/panel";
$route['default_controller'] = "main/index";
```

At first run, it will automatically go to main/index, it works fine, but when i click the panel link it says **Object not found** so does the Home link **Object no found**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you better have path relative to root in href:

```
   <a href="/main/index"> Home </a>
   <a href="/main/panel"> Panel </a>
```

or, even better like this:

```
   <a href="<?=$base_url;?>main/index"> Home </a>
   <a href="<?=$base_url;?>main/panel"> Panel </a>
```

next thing is views you are loading, correct way is to load one view in controller function:

```
   $this->load->view('home');
```

and in home.php you need to include your other views, home.php:

```
   <?php $this->load->view('templates/header');?>
   ...
   <!--YOUR HOME HTML GOES HERE-->
   ...
   <?php $this->load->view('templates/footer');?>
```

Now the routing. Be sure to use /index.php/[controller]/[function] links (unless you are using url rewrite like here http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/forums/viewthread/180566/)

Routing config:

```
   $route['default_controller'] = "main/index"; //this is the only thing you need to define
```

After all your pages will be accessible via such urls:

Index page: http://example.com/ , http://example.com/index.php/main/index

Panel page: http://example.com/index.php/main/panel

Comment: yes yes tried the rewrite thing it works but the problem is this http://localhost/projects/library/main/main/main/main/main/main/main/panel i just clicked the panel link multiple times but the links seems to be stacked every click i do

Comment: note the very first thing I mentioned - you should have proper links

Comment: ohh you mean even though i've already removed the index.php i have to include the base url?

Comment: yes, don't use relative, use absolute paths, they are safe way. Maybe you'll need to define website url in application/config/config.php if this is not working for you.

Comment: hmm okie, i've tried using the absolute path, but i've tried using the href="/main/index" it gives ang error ang the url is already wrong, instead of localost/projects/library/main/index it gives localhost/main/panel what's wrong here?. tried using the base_url() it works fine

Comment: go on with `base_url` then, the first approach is for those who have CI in root domain folder, not your case

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19199/discussion-between-lemoncodes-and-serg)

Comment: better way to create links use anchor function of url helper <? echo anchor('main/index')?> <? echo anchor('main/panel')?>